# How to disable the computing process in Eclipse for PHP?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

Each time I type the PHP symbol $ or the quotes then the IDE frozes because it opens the computing dialog

[image]

How to disable this process ?

Comment: If you mean the **content assist** you can disable the autoactivation of it in the `Editor > Content Assist` settings for the PHP Editor.

Comment: This should not happen in the current version since the content assist proposals are now computed asynchronously and no longer in the UI thread. The observed behavior indicates that you use an outdated version. Please upgrade. ([This video shows PHP content assist performance Oxygen.2 vs. Oxygen.3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJNzMGrbXbI&t=231s)).